# How do I average elements of a matrix according to an identity matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a 333x1 vector of values ('data') and each of the cells in the vector correspond to a range of 1 of 13 subcategories. The identities of each of these subcategories are stored in a separate identity matrix ('id'). I'd like to calculate the sum of the values within the original data matrix that have a similar identity.

e.g. pretending for this example that 'data' and 'id' are 8x1 vectors

data = [1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1]

id   = [1;2;1;2;3;3;1;3]

- sum of id 1: 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 3
- sum of id 2: 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1
- sum of id 3: 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1

I'm sure that there is a really easy fix for this, however I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks for your time

Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
numCategories = 13;
totals = zeros(numCategories,1);

for idnum = 1:numCategories
   totals(idnum) = sum((id==idnum).*data);
end
```

**EDIT**: As knedlsepp pointed out in the comments, the [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function accomplishes exactly what the above code does in one line.

```
accumarray(id,data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another twist...

What if I need to calculate the sum of similar elements of the data matrix. So, if data = [2;1;1;0;0;0;2;2]

Comment: @MacShine I'm not sure what the twist is. Is it just the fact that the `data` matrix is allowed to have 2's?

Comment: yep. Sorry, my computer decided to delete my post before I'd finished it. The idea is that I need to create a different sum for each unique element in data. The values in data range from 0 - 5.

Comment: So the elements in `data` would function as both values and IDs? In that case just use `data==idnum` in the above code instead.

Comment: Awesome. You're a legend!

Comment: `accumarray(id,data)` would also be an option to do this.

Comment: @knedlsepp It seems I've reinvented the wheel. ;) `accumarray` solves this exact problem. I'll have to remember that one. Thanks.